# Why is this borrow still "active"?

Tags: rust

This is a simplified example of something I've encountered:

```rust
trait Bla<'a> {
    fn create(a: &'a Foo) -> Self;
    fn consume(self) -> u8;
}

struct Foo;
impl Foo {
    fn take(&mut self, u: u8) {}
}

struct Bar {
    foo: Foo,
}

impl Bar {
    fn foobar<'a, 'b, B: Bla<'b>>(&'a mut self)
    where 'a: 'b {
        let u = {
            // immutable borrow occurs here
            // type annotation requires that `self.foo` is borrowed for `'b`
            let foo: &'b Foo = &self.foo;
            let b = B::create(foo);
            b.consume()
        };

        // error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.foo` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
        self.foo.take(u);
    }
}
```

Why is `self.foo` still considered to be borrowed even after exiting the block it was borrowed on, with everything that used the borrow also dropped?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The data might *flow* to another place.
To understand why the compiler is correct that the immutable borrow *might* still exist, consider the following implementation of `Bla` that is valid:

```rust
#![feature(once_cell)]

// The data stored in this global static variable exists for the entirety of runtime.
static REFS: SyncLazy<Mutex<Vec<&'static Foo>>> = SyncLazy::new(|| Mutex::new(vec![]));

struct Bad;
impl Bla<'static> for Bad {
    fn create(a: &'static Foo) -> Self {
        // The reference can go somewhere other than `Self`!
        REFS.lock().unwrap().push(a);
        Bad
    }

    fn consume(self) -> u8 {
        // Even if `self` is consumed here, 
        // `self` doesn't necessarily destroy the immutable borrow.
        0
    }
}
```

When your generic `foobar` function accepts any valid implementation of `Bla`, a valid implementation might take a `&'static` borrow that guarantees the borrow to last for the entire runtime. Therefore, it **is** an error because `consume` does not guarantee that the immutable borrow goes away.

---

You are probably looking for the `for<>` syntax as that will allow the `Bad` implementation to exist but will disallow anyone from calling `foobar` with `Bad`:

```rust
impl Bar {
    fn foobar<B: for<'b> Bla<'b>>(&mut self) {
        let u = {
                let foo: &Foo = &self.foo;
                let b = B::create(foo);
                b.consume()
        };
        self.foo.take(u);
    }
}
fn main() {
    Bar::foobar::<Bad>(&mut Bar { foo: Foo })
    // ^ error: implementation of `Bla` is not general enough
    // | `Bad` must implement `Bla<'0>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
    // | ...but it actually implements `Bla<'static>`
}
```

If this isn't the case, you might have to provide more implementation details rather than an example causing the diagnostic error.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer, and for giving me yet another thing to read about Rust (HRTBs)

Answer (score 6):

Normally, when you don't specify your own lifetime,  the lifetime of an immutable borrow to a variable ends when the variable goes out of scope. But in your code, you are specifying an explicit lifetime `'b` of the immutable borrow.

To the borrow checker, the only thing known about the lifetime `'b` is that it is a subset of `'a` (due to `where 'a: 'b`). In particular, the borrow checker will not assume that the scope of the immutable borrow ends at `}`, because nothing of that sort is specified about `'b`.

The compiler actually says this out loud:

> // type annotation requires that `self.foo` is borrowed for `'b`

### Summary

> Why is self.foo still considered to be borrowed even after exiting the block it was borrowed on, with everything that used the borrow also dropped?

Because the lifetime you specify does not end when the block ends. The borrow checker does not care about that some variables related to the borrow goes out of scope.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The borrow `'b` ends when it is no longer used, not when any variable goes out of scope. The problem is that both `'a` and `'b` are chosen by the caller, so it's impossible for `foobar` to know that `'b` is no longer used at the point of the error.

Comment: I am saying the same thing you are saying. What part of my answer makes you think I am saying something else?

Comment: First, you said: "Normally [...] the lifetime of an immutable borrow to a variable ends when the variable goes out of scope." This is not usually the case; the lifetime of a borrow normally ends well before the variable goes out of scope. The scope of a variable holding a value is only the upper bound. This is not a matter of NLL, either; even lexical borrows don't *normally* last the entire lifetime of the variable they borrow.

Comment: But OK, let's suppose you're talking about the *longest possible* lifetime. But then you go on to say "But in your code, you are specifying an explicit lifetime `'b`". The contrast between this and the previous sentence implies that the previous sentence does not imply here. Someone who isn't familiar with how borrowck works already could interpret this as meaning: "In *this* code, the lifetime of the borrow *doesn't* end when the variable goes out of scope." Which is just confusing because the variable in question is in the caller's scope, not in `foobar`.

Comment: The phrasing of your answer strikes me as saying that merely *making lifetime parameters explicit* changes how long their corresponding borrows last. Of course, this isn't true: implicit lifetime parameters (where permitted) are just as limiting as explicit ones. I don't think you *are wrong* about how borrowck works. I do think *the explanation in this answer* might unintentionally mislead people into believing false things about the borrow checker.

Comment: To avoid such ambiguity, I recommend avoiding the words "scope" and "subset" when discussing lifetimes and borrows, since their jargon meanings don't apply to lifetimes in an intuitive way, and using them in a loose sense or mixing ideas like the *scope of a variable* with the *lifetime of a borrow* is likely to cause more confusion than it resolves.